# Is there an easy way to use a static `index.html` page in docusaurus (2.0.4)?

Tags: react-hooks, docusaurus

I have an existing webpgage and would like to wrap it with docusaurus (2.0.4).

I have the `index.html` file in the `static` folder together with other assets, basically copied the complete hompeage into `static`.

I tried to add let docusaurus redirect to the `index.html` by modifying the `pages/index.js` file like this:

```js
import React from 'react';

function HomePage() {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        // Redirect to the static index.html
        window.location.href = '/index.html';
    }, []);

    // Render an empty component
    return null;
}

export default HomePage;
```

The redirect is being picked up, but somehow the html is never displayed but the page keeps reloading again and again.

Any help for solving this appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you're redirecting to the same page. Since this was already picked up (you hit the index already), you just need to redirect it to the non-index page, e.g. some page from your docs, like "docs/welcome" window.location.href = '/docs/welcome'